# Can AngularJS apps / modules contain controllers from other apps / modules?

Tags: angularjs

Can I create a module for authentication and then bind to its controllers from a view in another app / module?  For example, creating a common LoginController and then have login pages in my other apps that would use this controller?  If so, how?  I cannot find any examples but the docs make me think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so long as you have a script/module loaded up and set as the dependency of your app used for the ng-app or for manually bootstrapping the app then you can use any of the controllers/providers defined in those modules.

```js
angular.module('A',['B']);
angular.module('B', []).controller('MyController',function($scope){ $scope.doSomething = function(){alert('did something')}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="A">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have multiple modules by that you can separate out your code.

Basically you can create a separate module for your LoginController, like

`angular.module('authentication',[])
.controller('LoginController', function($scope){
  //code here
});`

then you main app module you should add this module

`angular.module('app',['authentication']`

Then you can use this app module as `ng-app` or you could bootsrap the same module.